# Realm returns empty object when open the database

Tags: node.js, electron, realm, ipc

I am using Realm(JS) version 11.9.0 and Electron 24.0.0.
I'm trying to set up a local database in my Electron app, but it goes wrong for unknown reasons.
As soon as I open the Realm database with the specified configuration I see that an empty object is returned.

By the way, the database is created because I see it appear in my directory, but as soon as I add items and want to retrieve items, I get an empty object in both cases.
I also do not see any error message in my Electron log environment or console.

So it's hard to pinpoint exactly where things go wrong.
Am I maybe missing something?

Here's the sample code:

main.ts

```
  import Realm from "realm";
    
    const TaskSchema = {
        name: "Task",
        properties: {
          _id: "int",
          name: "string",
          priority: "int?",
          progressMinutes: "int?",
        },
        primaryKey: "_id",
      };
      const PersonSchema = {
        name: "Person",
        properties: {
          name: "string",
          age: "int?",
        },
      };
      const DogSchema = {
        name: "Dog",
        properties: {
          name: "string",
          owner: "Person?",
          age: "int?",
        },
      };
      const CatSchema = {
        name: "Cat",
        properties: {
          name: "string",
        },
      };


let realm:Realm;

ipcMain.handle('createConnection', async (event, message) => {
  console.log('message',message)
    const encryptionKey = new Int8Array(64);    
    try {
      realm = await Realm.open(
        {
            schema: [TaskSchema,PersonSchema,DogSchema,CatSchema],
            path: "test.realm",
            encryptionKey,
        }
    );
    }catch(err){
      console.log("check issue:",err)
    }

  return {
    status: "ok",
    test: realm // returns Realm {}
  }
})


ipcMain.handle('createCat', async (event, message) => {

  try {
    let cat: Realm.Object;

    realm.write(() => {
      cat = realm.create("Cat", { name: "Max" });
    });
  }catch(err){
    console.log("Check issue:",err)
  }

  console.log('message',message)
  return {
    status: "ok"
  }
})


ipcMain.handle('getCat', async (event, message) => {

    let cats = realm.objects("Cat");

    console.log("cats: ",cats) // returens {}


  return {
    status: "ok",
  }
})
```

Does anyone have more experience with this within Realm-Nodejs and Electron?

Thank you in advance.

Comment: Have you tried to `console.log(realm)` inside `.handle`?

Comment: I already tried this, I get a an empty "Realm {}" response back. Unfortunately, there was also little documentation about this..  I already moved to Sqlite cipher.

Answer (score 0):

Realm objects are native and cannot be displayed by javascript, you can however still access their properties.